# Windows registry settings do not take effect on IE 8

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I am running Internet Excplorer version 8.0.6001 on Windows XP SP3. I want to change the default search engine for IE without using the user interface. So, I modified these registries:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\
- HKEY_CURRENT_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes\

However the modifications never took effect even if I rebooted the computer itself.
So how can I modify the default search engine for IE 8 using windows registry ?

Comment: I've had joy with the Registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchUrl can you try that?

Comment: I check that too, I modified it but it did not take effect. Only when I change through the GUI of this browser then the effect is immediate

Comment: If you was to get sysinternals and load a program called ProcMon set the filter to IExplore.exe and then change this setting you will see what registry/files/etc are changed and it will help you determine what IE does during this change.